# Is internal friction angle isotropic in soil?

Tags: geotechnical-engineering, soil-mechanics

I am studying geotechnical engineering and specifically the chapter in B.M. Das book of the same name, 6th edition.

On the topic of shear forces, reference to internal friction angle, $\phi$ is made. My understanding is that the friction angle is the angle in a right triangle with legs of magnitude $F_N$,force normal to a specific plane, and $\mu F_N$, the friction force parallel with the plane, where $tan(\phi)=\frac{F_N \mu }{F_N}=\mu$.

My question is if $\phi$ is constant for all planes in a specific soil, i.e. isotropic, or can it be anisotropic?

Further, is the answer the same for rocks and minerals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, research has shown inherent soil anisotropy, such as naturally deposited sand's bedding angle, has a substantial correlation with the stress-strain response of sand. [research](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311412282_Influence_of_soil_inherent_anisotropy_on_the_behavior_of_crushed_sand-steel_interfaces)

> For instance, Oda and
> Koishikawa (1979), Siddiquee et al. (2001), and Azami
> et al. (2010) showed that the bearing capacity of shallow
> foundations resting on inherently anisotropic sand
> decreases with the increase in the inclination of the bedding
> plan

Quoted from the linked document!

Rocks of a sedimentary nature, as well, are showing major differences in shear friction angle. Slates is a good example!

[image: shear strength and bedding angle]